# Wrong topology or just UV viewport's artefact?

Tags: uv, topology

Strange artefact in UV map view. Some "ghost" faces.

The faces that contain rounded cut are in the same plane. So I decided to leave N-gons because of flat plane.

The texture and MatCap looks good.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

Finally I decided change topology to proper loop cuts. So UV map strange artefacts have gone.
[image]

Comment: Artifices From what I can deduct.

Comment: Likely caused by the ngons in your model. Creating a clean topology will likely resolve the issue.

Comment: add a color grid texture and test if it deforms it.

Comment: that's the point, checker textures looks great. But UV map - not. I think I need to change the topology, because it is uncertain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some of your vertices are over-scaled on the Y (yellow).

It could also be from vertices that don't have an edge.

Try scaling down on the Y (yellow arrow below)

[image: Try scaling these]

Comment: I'm afraid I didn’t understand what means over-scaled vertices. I double checked: all vertices within the mesh and there are no doubles and lost. I think these artifacts are because of poor topology despite good texturing result.

Comment: No worries (if I'm correct it goes like this),

The Mesh is made up of the vertices (points) that can be manipulated in 3D space to make up your 3D Object. When those points are connected to 2 or more points, they create a face (or however many sides).

triangle as having only 3 points, but a square would have 4.

The program uses the information of these points to tell how to render the face (surface) inbetween all of them

But, strange issues can happen if you have a lot of points that are not connected to anything.

<https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/film-games/ngons-triangles-bad>

Comment: @su1736, if that was helpful, be sure to mark the response. Otherwise, feel free to ask more specific questions on un-answered topics.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! Your answer lead me to make maybe not graceful but technically right topology.